# UpdateToken() method does not refresh the access token

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, keycloak, flutter-web

Need help with the below-faced issue in the implementation of Keycloak redirection in the flutter web application.

Flutter Package Used : [keycloak_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/keycloak_flutter) | Flutter Package

The above package has used Keycloak JS adapter implementation. to achieve keycloak redirection in the flutter web application using the below reference.

Reference : [Securing Applications and Services Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter)

Describe the bug :

Using the package I am trying to refresh the access token by calling the update token method which makes the refreshtoken API request from keyclaok.js. but the request returns Status 400 Bad Request, then I checked the request in the browser tool(network tab), and the refresh_token is passed as undefined. I also tried to pass -1 as a parameter to the update token() which forcefully refresh the token.

access_token expires in 1 min

Expected behavior :
The update token method should refreshtoken if the access token is expiry.

Also Observed

Immediately after successfully login OnAuthLogout event is fired
the token expired event is not fired even after the token is expired
Thanks in Advance.